# JavaScript - Async/Await - How to Return result from nested functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm new to Node.js and having difficulty working with async/await model. The issue I'm having is with nested function calls returning data in an async/await method, I always get `'undefined'`. My functions structure is like this:

```
const findCustomerOrder = async (id) => {
    const orders = await Order.find({custoemrId:id})
        .then(async (order) => {
            if(order)
                {
                  const products = await findProductsByOrderId(order._id)
                        .then(async (result) => {
                            for(const r in result){
                                console.log("Product ID: ", result._id);
                            }
                        });
                }
            else
                console.log("order not found");     

        });
}

const findProductsByOrderId = async (id) => {
    try{
        const products = await Products.find({orderId:id}, (error, data) => {
            if(error) console.log(error);
            else 
                return data;
        });
    }
    catch(err){
            return 'error!!';
    }
}
```

I understand that if the top-level call is async/await then all the nested calls should be awaited as well that I've tried to do.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of all the `then`, and also of the callback in the DB query. Use only `await`. It will make the whole code a lot easier to reason about and it should also solve your issue as part of the restructuring.

In the example below I also added a loop over the orders, because you are fetching *all* orders, as array, but then your code was behaving as if it got only one. I also fixed the products loop.

However, the way you fetch products doesn't seem to be right anyway, see my comment below. I didn't fix it because I don't know how your database structure looks, so I don't know what the right way would be.

```js
async function findCustomerOrder (id) {
  const orders = await Order.find({ customerId: id })
  
  for (const order of orders) {
    console.log(`Order ID: ${order._id}`)
    
    const products = await findProductsByOrderId(order._id)
    for (const product of products) {
      console.log(`Product ID: ${product._id}`);
    }
  }
}

async function findProductsByOrderId (id) {
  // Note: I don't think this is right. It seems to find all
  // products with the given ID - which will always be one -
  // and that ID would be the _product_ ID and not the order ID.
  return await Products.find({ _id: id })
}
```

<sub>Preemptive comment reply: The `return await` is intentional, and [this is why](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/1442).</sub>

Comment: Your observation is correct and a typo on my part. `Products.find({ _id: id })
}` actually reads `Products.find({ orderId: id })`
}

Comment: what are the implications of using `for` in this context. My understanding is that it is synchronous. What can be an asynchronous equivalent here?

Comment: Your function is `async`. So the loop body (and in fact even the condition, etc.) can be asynchronous as well.

Comment: Is for/foreach async safe and will run after async operation is completed in your code sample? Or should I change with something else?

Comment: I don't understand the question. There is an `await` before. Why wouldn't it be safe? (And what would "not safe" even mean?) I think you would get a better feeling for async JavaScript by just playing with it and testing the different scenarios (for example with artificial longer delays).

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the then and also the callback and you can do something like below

```js
const findCustomerOrder = async(id) => {
  try {
    const orders = await Order.find({
      custoemrId: id
    });

    if (orders) {
      let promiseArray = [];
      orders.forEach(order => {
        promiseArray.push(findProductsByOrderId(order._id));
      });
      let results = await Promise.all(promiseArray);

      return results;
    }

    return "order not found";
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}

const findProductsByOrderId = async(id) => {
  try {
    const products = await Products.find({
      _id: id
    });
    return products;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: `} catch (err) { throw err; }` is pretty pointless, don't wrap the code in `try` altogether